# How to Build a Signed Bundle (AAB)?

Tags: android, build, bundle, signing

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to build an AAB for my app, which apparently is now required to publish in PlayStore. Using AndroidStudio V3.5.3, if I select "Build->GenerateSignedBundle/APK" and supply the signing info req'd, nothing happens: no processing, no output produced.

"Build->BuildBundle(s)/APK(s)" works, but the output is unsigned.
"Run->Run app" and "Run->Debug app" work, but same as above.

**What am I missing?**

I've read all the doc I can find but nothing helpful.

Comment: if you import signingConfigs to gradle file, so you can output .aab file by root "Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)>Build Bundle(s)"

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in Android Studio version 4.1.1. Does anybody found a solution to this?

Comment: @PouriyaKhalaj I have already imported my signing config to gradle file. But still only `debug.keystore` is being taken. Then I found only `debug.keystore` file inside `.android` folder. How to have `release.keystore` inside `.android` folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App bundles are an optional way to publish your app not mandatory. You can generate your signed bundle/APK from Android Studio > Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK and follow the process...

[image]

Comment: As I said in my question, that's exactly what I did, with no result.

Comment: oh sorry, I must have missed that! Do you reach the build variants step?

Comment: Yes, I did but "Finish" did nothing. Strangely, I just now tried doing the exact same thing I've done for days and I got further, but now getting a new error message. I'm Investigating...

Comment: Well, I restarted AndroidStudio, did a Clean Build and re-started ADB. Now everyting is peachy. Another AndroidStudio bug I guess.

Comment: Well whaddya know, now they're not optional but mandatory, and requires sucky software to do it just like Apple! 

Any dev who has a finished app and wants to publish it suddenly needs a desktop PC with 24GB of RAM to publish an app for a device with grandma specs. :"device":sad:face

Comment: I'm in Android Studio and I don't see the menu as shown above, I see 4 commands:

Make (inactive) - 

Recompile (inactive) - 

 Analyze APK (no visible action) - 

Deploy Module to App engine (message from expo: The project does not contain any App engine modules...)

I also see a Build Output window that says "build finished", but I don't see any recent .APK or .AAB files in the project folder

Answer (score 10):

Easy way to do this issue, please follow my Steps.
Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:
[image]
Step 4:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Okay I just got this and think I should be able to help. I got the exact same behavior, and it turns out that the issue was Android Studio incorrectly saved my keystore and key passwords. When I deleted the autofill and typed them in correctly, it finally worked.

Not sure why they would have the "Remember Passwords" feature if it doesn't work, and not sure why it fails silently like that. Hope this helps anyone going forward.

Comment: Same here, I had to type my passwords again to make it work. Thanks for the tip because it drove me crazy for an entiere day!
By the way it should be the accepted answer...

Comment: it don't work with me :(

Comment: @While generating `.aab` even though I selected `release keystore`, `.aab` is taking only `debug keystore` which is available in `.android` folder. How to make `release keystore` file available in `.android` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, from Android Studio, go to:

1. `Build` menu > `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`
2. Choose `Android App Bundle` (just like the attached screenshot)
3. Next

[image]

More information from [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-apk-to-app-bundle-made-simple-e12c52e8641).

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in CLI, you can use `jarsigner`

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <my-key-store>.keystore -storepass <password> app-release.aab <keysotre-alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding project and then generating signed bundle

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart Android Studio and rebuild. Then I had to create a new key store form scratch. Now it's working.

I'm running version 3.6.3

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that the filename in Key Store Path was invalid. Sadly, Android Studio shows no error about this. I corrected the filename and then everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just run from terminal the command from root folder:

> flutter build appbundle