# Unable to install the .apk generated from .aab due to signing issues

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have installed **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 for Mac (~993 MiB)** recently. I have created `.aab` file from `Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK`. While generating `.aab` I have given all the required details like keystore file path, alias and password. After generating `.aab` I tired to generate `.apk` from `.aab` by using following command,

```
sudo bundletool build-apks --bundle=<.aab location> --output=<.apk location>
```

Then I encountered with following warning,

> WARNING: The APKs won't be signed and thus not installable unless you
> also pass a keystore via the flag --ks. See the command help for more
> information.

Now, If I am unable to install the generated `.apk` file due to signing issues.

May I know the reason behind this warning though I have given all the required details while generating `.aab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a requirement of the Android platform that all APKs must be signed to be installed on a device, so your requirement of "installing unsigned APKs" is simply not possible.

[Solutions to get apk from aab](https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues/153#issuecomment-611417620)

Comment: You answers describes the temporary solutions for testing purpose. But to submit app to playstore we need to generate signed `.aab`. How can I do that?

Comment: To generate aab just select the `Generate Signed Bundle/Apk from the build tab in android studio

Comment: May I know the reason behind this warning?

Comment: The aab file you're trying to unpack is not a signed aab

Comment: But I have given all required details while I was trying to generate `.aab` like keystore path, alias and password. And May I know how to create signed `.aab`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70164745/13533028 This answer should help

Comment: I understood from the question you pinged that `.android` folder should have `keystore` files for signing. but in my `.android` folder I found only `debug.keystore`. How to have `release.keystore` inside `.android` folder?

Comment: Put it in the root folder of the app you're buildin and then run the code again

Comment: I copied `release keystore` file to app's root location and then ran app in both `debug` and `release` mode. But still app bundle signs with `debug keystore` and still `release keystore` file is not there inside `.android` folder. Any alternatives to try?

Comment: Keep the debug keystore aside.
https://www.geekdashboard.com/extract-apk-files-from-aab/  See this document where it talks about signign with release key